# pop up ads in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ads

I have been playing Games from Djinnworks, Like Line surfer and others.
How do they have pop ups of there new apps?
I have searched over the internet, couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to do this and update the ad online? Like for there new game wing suit Stickman, it has ads that change weekly without an update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, please do not do this in a mobile application. This is a horrible user experience, and I would not be surprised if Apple started rejecting applications that do this.

Comment: Why? It's a good way to get more earnings.

Comment: Pop-ups of any kind interrupt the user as they are working with your application, and are particularly disruptive in a mobile application. This is terrible design, and shows contempt for the people who are using your application. There are many other, much better ways to make money (such as providing a quality product that they will pay for, or advertising in an nonintrusive way). Again, Apple has in the past acted to prevent applications from doing things that adversely impact the user experience, so this is not a good long-term strategy.

Comment: What's a good way alternative to this? Other then ad banners on bottom of app?

Answer (score 0):

place the ad as image on your server and load it from there in the app, then you can change the image on the server (and therefore also the ad in your app) without an app update.

you could also do something like: check for a new ad only every two weeks, to save bandwidth.

Comment: How would I make the ad pop up and then close when x is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use cross promotion with a service like http://chartboost.com.

This allows you to show only your own apps and have control over when they are displayed. This allows you to give the best user experience you can while still promoting your other apps.